# How can I call "EthernetSettings" under Settings/WirelessSettings?

Tags: android, settings

I'm trying to call the activity that named Etherent configuration.

Which placed on **Settings > Wireless & networks > Ethernet settings**.

I found just "Wireless & networks" activity deep, I just called it like,

```
startActivity( new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS) );
```

but couldn't find the way to call "Ethernet settings" under that above.

Any solutions? Thank you for reading.

(my device is android version 2.3.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such activity in standard Android. You are welcome to contact your device manufacturer to see if there is some publicly documented and supported `Intent` for launching your desired activity on their devices.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I added classes.jar from build out folder, and import it, so I could access that all things, thank you :)

Comment: @Gioskhan have u solved it..if solved please ans here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51981852/how-to-redirect-user-to-ethernet-settings-screen-in-android-programmatically/51982201#51982201

Answer (score 1):

I know it's old thread, but this might be helpful to someone

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent( new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.Settings$EthernetSettingsActivity" ));
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Quoting from other answer for clarity: *"There is no such activity in **standard Android"***